# How can I cache Haml templates inside ruby

Tags: ruby, templates, caching, haml

I'm writing a simple web framework with ruby. I'm rendering my templates with

```
renderer = Haml::Engine.new(template_path, ...)
html_output = renderer.render(Object.new, params)
```

but this gives me only last rendered html output. Suppose that I have a view like this

```
-if title.include? 'Admin Page'
  =title
-else
  %a
    Test
```

In every request it re-render html part of the template. Is there any way to get cachable version of this template for production to get rid of re-render. Caching pure html isn't enough here because title may change in request.

Firstly I thought this is impossible because result file must be ruby file and look like this.

```
output = ''
if title.include? 'Admin Page'
  output << title
else
  output << '<a>Test</a>'
end
```

but after a search I read that Haml files can be cached but I can't figure out how to achieve this. Can I cache Haml templates, if so how can I do this? Is my approach true in this concept or am I missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your question with details. Provide an example Haml template, and two or three calls to using it, and which parts you hope to be cached, and which must be recalculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with Tilt's cache mechanizm.

```
require 'tilt'
cache = Tilt::Cache.new
cache.fetch(path_of_your_file, Tilt.new(path_of_your_file,options))
```

this code will cache the Tilt object which includes the parsed version of your haml file. In my code cache key is the path of the file, you can give it whatever you want.

Forexample in development mode I'm using `[path_of_file, mtime_of_file]` so cache renews for that file whenever I modified the haml file.

Answer (score 0):

> *after a search I read that Haml files can be cached but I can't figure out how to achieve this*

I don't know what you read, but I do not imagine that it means what you think it means.

- You can read (and cache) the `.haml` template code.
- You can can parse the template code with the `Haml` engine so that it is ready to render, and cache that result so that you can run the template repeatedly on a new set of variables and get different output.
- And, as you suggest, you can cache the HTML results for a particular set of variables so that you don't need to run the template if you've already seen the correct results.

But you cannot do what you seem to be suggesting—have Haml cache portions of the resulting HTML output while having other portions change—unless you are chaining together multiple templates with their own caching systems.